# Как можно определить на какую букву заканчивается слово?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть бот для вк. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы бот мог читать последнюю букву слова которое пришлет человек. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: исправьте свое "*ля" пожалуйста) и не могли бы вы подсказать, в каком виде на сервер приходит слово?

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему бот у вас на JS. Поэтому очень просто

`var lastLetter = message.slice(-1);`

В `message` должна быть строка с сообщением.